# Atmel-ICE programming atsam4sd32c

Tags: arm, atmel, atmelstudio, jtag, swd

I am having problems with the programming of a custom pcb which is using the 32-bit atsam4sd32c ARM Cortex M4. I am unable to program the microcontroller trough the JTAG/SWD interface using the ATMEL-ICE debugger. However I am able to get the device signature identifier using the atmel studio 7.0 command promt. Doing manual chip erases and resets is also possible.

When I try to program the board via the atmel studio 7.0 software the upload hangs at 14%.

We have tried a lot but not progress is being made.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It sounds most likely to be an issue with the board itself, which a) we can't help much with, and b) isn't programming. From a quick look at the datasheet, the JTAG/SWD pins are muxed with GPIOs, which makes me suspect you have stuff hooked up to those pins causing signal integrity problems. The NRST and ERASE pins are not muxed, and it seems quite possible that the debug probe might initially read the chip ID at some lowest-common-denominator clock rate, but then use a device-specific faster clock for programming once it knows what it's talking to, which would fit the behaviour described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses.

I was aware of the fact that this question was a little unfit for this forum. 
But I hoped there might be people here who had experience with the atmel ARM series microcontrollers.

I did contact Atmel support and aventually that helped out.

The problem was in de hardware design of the JTAG lines. I was unaware of the need for pull-up resistors on all JTAG lines (TMS, TDI, TDO, NRST and TCK).

after we applied the resistors programming worked fine.

greetings,

Maarten Roozendaal